# Use Log4J in custom module

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I want to use Log4J into my application. I have a limited resources and I want to use just the basic part of Log4J. Can you tell which package I need to use just for basic logging.

[image]

P.S In order to use just basic Log4J which packages I can remove?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need the first two, and if it's Maven-based build then only the second, Log4j Core and the first will be added as a transitive dependency.

You could also use this entry in `pom.xml` if you're using Maven or similar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Andrey, you need the core and the api jars. Note that the OSGi stuff is still a work in progress. About wich packages could be removed from the core jar: I see you also posted your question to the log4j mailing list. I'll answer there so that the whole log4j team can chip in.

Be aware though the the core jar contains config files in addition to .class files. If you rebuild a jar with a custom subset you *must* include those config files or the api will not recognize your jar as an implementation.